# how to save modified file in linux using shell script before shutdown/reboot

Tags: html, linux, shell

I have a file1.txt and the file content is "a b c" and when dynamically i am changing the content of the file1.txt to "1 2 3" through html page.when I reboot my system the content of the file1.txt are not updating that means the content will be same as "a b c".how can I save my file1.txt file before reboot/shutdown using shell scripting.

---

I have an file3.htm in that page I am searching for a matching string and file3.htm and replacing that string with the replacing string and that out put I am diverting it to other file using sed command

```
sed -e 's/Ip_address/'$IP'/g' file3.htm > file4.htm
```

Comment: How are you changing the file? Post some code, please.

Comment: I have an file3.htm
in that page I am searching for a matching string and file3.htm and replacing that string with the replacing string and that out put I am diverting it to other file using sed commond 
sed -e 's/Ip_address/'$IP'/g' file3.htm > file4.htm

Comment: where IP taking from Html page

Comment: You can use sync to manually synchronise the kernel file buffers with the files on the hard disk. I did not put it as a solution, because this is not a guarantee. If data is still stuck in user space buffers, the sync call does nothing. Give it a try!